# PHP number_format(): rounding numbers and then formatting as currency

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am trying to create an ecommerce store and our prices need to fluctuate with the exchange rate for different countries so I'm dealing with a lot of decimal places.

What I want to do is round the original price to the nearest full number (as in they can keep the change). But then I want to format that as a currency with two decimal places.

```
<?php
$number = 12345.6789;
echo $number;  // outputs '12345.6789'
$number = number_format($number,0);
echo $number;  // outputs '12,346'
$number = number_format($number,2);
echo $number;  // outputs '12.00'
?>
```

After formatting to no decimal places it starts reading the ',' as the decimal separator instead of the thousands separator and formats that for two decimal places.

It also gives the following error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\wamp64\www\Lifting365\test.php on line 6
```

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: You're overwriting the number each time, so the last time you format it, you're formatting `12,346` instead of `12345.6789`. Try `round()` or `ceil()` instead of `number_format()` if you want to round it to a whole number before formatting it to money.

Comment: @aynber, yes that is what I needed thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation, number_format returns a string value, you can't reuse it as a number.
Use the function [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to round your number, if you want to round it to the direct upper integer use [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) instead.

```
number_format(round(12345.6789), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

// apply intval to get the low integer value (for change purposes)

```
$number = 12345.6789;
echo $number;  // outputs '12345.6789'
echo intval($number)."<br/>";  // outputs '12345'
echo number_format(intval($number),0,'.','.'); // outputs '12.345'
echo number_format(intval($number),0,'.',','); // outputs '12,345'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function and then `number_format`.

```
// returns 12,346.00
number_format(round(12345.6789), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `number_format` accepts 4 parameters. Per default a point will be used as decimal seperator and comma as thousands seperator (12345.6789 become 12,346 after your first call; as excepted). It's not explicitly documented but number_format also rounds.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

You are getting an error because you reuse the same variable `$number`. After your first call to `number_format` you dont have a float value anymore.

```
<?php
    $number = 12345.6789;
    echo $number."<br>";                            // outputs 12345.6789
    echo number_format($number,0)."<br>";           // outputs 12,346  
    echo number_format($number,2)."<br>";           // outputs 12,345.68
?>
```

If you are not sure what is in your variable you can apply `floatval` to it.

```
echo number_format(floatval($number),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function that you're looking for is money_format() http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php have a good read through the manual page (including the comments)